# Select distinct on DocumentDB and C#

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb, document-database

I am having a challenge retrieving data from my DocumentDB using C#.

I get the expected results when I run the query below in my Azure DocumentDB data explorer. Ignore the use of contains query, it's a dynamically crafted query

```
select distinct c.model from c   where  ( CONTAINS (c.manufacturer, \"BMW\") )
```

Attempting to run the same query on c# gives me an error

```
var dblink = UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DocumentDbDatabase"], "Conversation");
var models = _dbclient.CreateDocumentQuery<dynamic>(dblink, "select distinct c.model from c   where  ( CONTAINS (c.manufacturer, "BMW") )").ToList();
```

The error I get is `incorrect syntax near distinct`

Where is the error emanating from?

Comment: Try escaping quote for BMW.  try  \"BMW\".

Comment: If you have strongly typed objects, you might as well try LINQ

Comment: @RafatSarosh I already did that. the query however is breaking at the second word which is distinct

Comment: @bit I am not using strongly typed objects

Answer (score 0):

You may want to upgrade to the latest .Net SDK (v1.22.0).

The syntax error here is from the SDK rather than the query service, given that support for DISTINCT was added recently. Upgrading to the latest SDK should fix the issue.